# reinstate mac file system on hard drive using windows

Tags: filesystems

During an attempt to get a journalled extended os-x external SSD recognised by Windows in order for files to be accessed, it was unwittingly initialised in windows7.

The data was subsequently recovered using macdrive.

The hope is to be able to reinstate the mac [os-x] file system on the drive, and then put the data back. is there any tool that can be used to do this, from within windows?  note: no mac machine is available for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cursory Google tells me that OSX uses the `HFS+` file system, which there are certainly no *free* Windows utilities to format a drive into.

http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm is a trialware program that claims to be able to format "For Mac", which may be the HFS+ file system you need.

Otherwise I suggest creating a LiveDisc of `PartedMagic` or a similar Linux Distribution, and using it to format the drive, since the simple fact is that Windows won't touch HFS+ and Macs won't touch NTFS. With PartedMagic, which you can put onto a USB and boot into, you should be able to format the drive to anything you need.

Comment: Transmac; that looks like the right stuff.  Many thanks for your help.  Very nice to have more than one possible course of action as well.

Comment: Transmac is the Windows Explorer of mac-formatted/mac file system drives. plug in the drive, start up the application, select in left panel the drive and watch the files all appear that were unreadable in Windows.  To my great relief the original data the owner of the drive had put on it was unaffected by the Windows initialisation.  Thanks again t jennings for your cursory ggl and not so cursory reply!